# request: Can't pipe responses to filesystem

Tags: node.js, express, request, fs

I am using express and also the npm: 'request-promise-native' module.
I see the resolved request object is full and everything is fine but he just creates an empty file in the filesystem without piping the content into the filesystem.

I also get no error message.
Would be nice if somebody can point me in the right direction.

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');
var fs = require('fs');

var receivedReq = await request(buildReq);
receivedReq.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("my.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `request-promise` or `request-promise-native` with streams [is discouraged by the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise#api-in-detail), because the memory usage is sub-optimal compared to `request`. If you're using a fairly recent version of `request-promise-native`, `request` itself is a `peerDependency`, so you already have it installed.

You can use it like so:

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

request(buildReq).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("my.html"));
```

If for some reason, you still want to use `request-promise-native` with streams, you can simply put `request-promise-native` in the `require` above, and it should work. There's no need to `await` the request before piping it.

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the response object. I need to write the file to the filesystem and keep the response object for further processing.

And after I received the response I am not able to stream anymore because streamable state has become false

Comment: OK, so exactly what "further processing" do you want to do? Do you want to stream to two places, or do you want to use the response normally (e.g. `response.text()`) later?